# Parsing the text in a cell and converting it into data in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms, datagrip

```
Table : test
|---------------------------------------------------------| 
|      descriptiona                                       |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|#*Summary: data1  #*Steps: data2  #*Result: data3        |        
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|#*Steps: data5  #*Summary: data6  #*Result: data4        |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

I want the data to be displayed as:

```
summary   steps   result
data1     data2   data3
data6     data5   data4
```

Tried using:

```
SELECT  substring(descriptiona, 1, charindex('*Steps', descriptiona)-2) AS Summary,
  substring(descriptiona, charindex('*Steps', descriptiona), (charindex('*Result', descriptiona) - charindex('*Steps', descriptiona)) -2 ) AS Steps,
       substring(descriptiona, charindex('*Result', descriptiona),len(descriptiona)) AS ActualResult
 from test;
```

But this only works for the first row.

Comment: This will be painful, especially with SQL Server, that has no proper regexp support. This task would be easier done on application side.

Comment: You should have normalized the schema right from the start and use different columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string and perform a conditional aggregation within a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([descriptiona] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('#*Summary: data1 #*Steps: data2 #*Result: data3')
,('#*Steps: data5 #*Summary: data6 #*Result: data4')

Select B.* 
 From  @YourTable
 Cross Apply ( Select Summary= stuff(max(case when charindex('Summary:',value)>0 then Value end),1,10,'')
                     ,Steps  = stuff(max(case when charindex('Steps:',value)>0 then Value end)  ,1,8,'')
                     ,Result = stuff(max(case when charindex('Result:',value)>0 then Value end) ,1,9,'')
                 From string_split([descriptiona],'#')
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Summary Steps   Result
data1   data2   data3
data6   data5   data4
```

**EDIT - 2012 Non Function Alternative**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([descriptiona] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('#*Summary: data1 #*Steps: data2 #*Result: data3')
,('#*Steps: data5 #*Summary: data6 #*Result: data4')

Select B.* 
 From  @YourTable
 Cross Apply ( Select Summary= stuff(max(case when charindex('Summary:',value)>0 then Value end),1,10,'')
                     ,Steps  = stuff(max(case when charindex('Steps:',value)>0 then Value end)  ,1,8,'')
                     ,Result = stuff(max(case when charindex('Result:',value)>0 then Value end) ,1,9,'')
                 From (
                        Select seq   = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                              ,value = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace([descriptiona],'#','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                      ) B1
             ) B
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It works. Could you explain me ```Cross Apply ( Select Summary= stuff(max(case when charindex('Summary:',value)>0 then Value end),1,10,'')```?
How does this work? Or if you could refer any documentation.

Comment: @PrateekSharma Always happy to help.   Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=efa7b78120563a192c1d675c96b4fe26   You will see that the CROSS APPLY with just the string_split() will generate multiple rows.  We just take those rows and apply a conditional aggregation while stripping out "Summary", "Steps" and "Result"

Comment: Is there an alternative for SQL Server 2012 without creating a function?

Comment: @PrateekSharma Sure, see the EDIT portion.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/25b305/14/0)

Just for fun, if you are running SQL Server 2016 or latest, this is a possible solution (not the prettiest, admittedly):

```
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(json_string, '$.Summary') as Summary,
    JSON_VALUE(json_string, '$.Steps') as Steps,
    JSON_VALUE(json_string, '$.Result') as Result
FROM (
        SELECT 
      '{"'+REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(SUBSTRING(description, 3, LEN(description)), ' ', ''),
          ':', '":"'),
        '#*', '","') 
        + '"}' AS json_string
FROM test) A
```

The idea is to get a JSON string from one of your `descriptions` and then parse it as such and extract relevant fields, e.g.

```
#*Summary: data1  #*Steps: data2  #*Result: data3
```

becomes

```
{"Summary":"data1","Steps":"data2","Result":"data3"}
```

There are a few caveats of course, mostly depending on what values you actually have in your table.